# Grid CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I created a  grid layout with 6 divs. If i write text in first div, it expands depending on the text, and so does all the divs in the row. But is it possible to do something so that only 1 div in a row expands, while others do not?

```css
.grid_body {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
   grid-column-gap: 17.5px;
   grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px, auto );
   grid-row-gap: 35px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 17.5px;
}

.grid_item {
   width: 300px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 5px solid rgb( 5, 214, 73, 1 );
}

.grid_item img {
   margin: 10px;
}

.grid_item a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
}

.grid_item a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.grid_item p {
   text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_body">
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequnt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequint, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequii </p></a>
 </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Probably. Where's your code?

Comment: I added code, look, please, in first div i added text, but 2 divs in a row expands too. I know that is property of grid, but i learn html and i wonder if i can write text, divs will expands differently

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `align-items: start;` to the grid container. Remember a row still stays a row, so this will give you "holes" in your layout.

If you need a [*masonry*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/) type of layout, you will be able to work with `grid-template-rows: masonry;` in the future. [As of now, Firefox is the only browser supporting this *behind a flag*.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_grid-template-rows_masonry)

```css
.grid_body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 17.5px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px, auto);
  row-gap: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 17.5px;
  align-items: start;
}

.grid_item {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid rgb( 5, 214, 73, 1);
}

.grid_item img {
  margin: 10px;
}

.grid_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.grid_item a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.grid_item p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_body">
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti. iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem
        sequnt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti. iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit,
        aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequint, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis
        praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti. iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequii </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item">
    <a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et
        harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim
        ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! and can the divs from the bottom move up to cover the empty space?

Comment: That is commonly called masonry layout. I've added information and linked a very good article on that in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been trying to find this information for 5 hours)))

Comment: Then why did you neither pick this as an answer, nor upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid_body {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
   grid-column-gap: 17.5px;
   grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px, auto );
   grid-row-gap: 35px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 17.5px;
   width:20px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
   border:thin black solid;
}

.grid_item {
   width: 300px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 5px solid rgb( 5, 214, 73, 1 );
}

.grid_item img {
   margin: 10px;
}

.grid_item a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
}

.grid_item a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.grid_item p {
   text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_body">
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>(bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb)Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequnt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequint, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequii </p></a>
 </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, qherahdkfbhsdjsgdkrygfbvasjvbgfhvbjhvbhsbhfkbvjuis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If i understand your problem os this is .....

In first i put extra code foe example....

Comment: OP is concerned about vertical extension, not horizontal (which would be addressable by `word-wrap`).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: I found out that is a type of a masonry grid. I learn html and I'm just experimenting)))